# is it permitted to make a snowman?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, games-toys, snow

Is it permitted to make a snowman? Or is it considered constructing a graven image?

Prompted by this:
http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/saudi-arabia-issues-fatwa---4967400

Comment: Welcome. It has been a while since you have asked a question!

Comment: How about drawing a smiley face on a snowcone?

Comment: Like these? ☃ ⛄ ⛇

Comment: Karet? Fire? Brimstone, another global flood or just flogging + stoning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Volume 3 Issue 8](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue8.pdf) of "Halachicly Speaking" (page 3) it is permissible for two reasons:

1. No one bows down to snowmen
2. A snowman does not last for very long.

Comment: boo to #1 y.d. 141 4. Says a Jew cannot make a human figure even for 'noy' is assur. If you can find someone who claims this is not a human figure that would be a different story.

Comment: @user6591, I'm just quoting ...

Comment: I know. I'm just commenting:) I don't downvote direct quotes from reputable sources. But I do comment on them.

Comment: @user6591, there may be a distinction between if the object would be worshiped, but it is not being made for that purpose, or if it isn't worshiped at all. כל הראוי לבילה אין בילה מעקבת בו

Comment: Is a snowman "graven"?

Comment: I dont think so based on the shulchan aruch and shach there. All you might get away with is maybe to say there would be no chashad for shehiya if found, but even this is not said by anyone. For the record the other svara is a chidush too, but not a contradiction to the simple halacha. Thats why I only gave this one a boo.

Comment: Avodah Zara is the next tractate I am going to learn after I finish Horayot. Should be interesting reading.

Comment: Would this be different in Antarctica?