# Can someone build a snowman on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, snow

Can one build a snowman on Shabbat? If not, what are the Issurim involved?

Do the issues of Boneh, Molid, Muktza, Makeh Bapatish etc apply?

Comment: Sort of related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52633

Answer (score 7):

Shmiras Shabbas Kihilchasa 16:44 assurs to make snowballs and snowmen on shabbas.

Rav Elyashiv in Vayishma Moshe pg 132 writes that is an issur derabannan and is similiar to melacha.In footnote 177 it's written that some hold the issur is boneh  (see Rambam 7:6 regarding collecting pieces and sticking them together to make one item is domeh to boneh ). Others hold that there is no boneh, but because of meamer,or because of making a form.

Rav Yitzchak Abadi (Shu"t Ohr Yitzchak Siman 192) holds there is no issur making snowballs and the like.However,since the main purpose of making snowballs is to throw at someone else it could be a problem of hotzah.

Comment: http://www.dinonline.org/2011/02/03/snowmen-and-snowballs-on-shabbos/

Comment: I believe that forming snow is also a melcha of "lash" - kneading.

Comment: Hotzaah, or, more likely, maavir daled (which is kinda the same thing)